# How to write if statement which has three conditions in Oracle db

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle database. I'm confused how to write if condition in the stored procedure.

I have four tables.

Table1 : t1

```
╔════════════╦═════╗
║ CustomerID ║ Year║
╠════════════╬═════╣
║ ACC20011   ║ 2001║
║ ACC30122   ║ 2001║
║ ACC12356   ║ 2002║
║ EVG12345   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23445   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23548   ║ 2003║
╚════════════╩═════╝
```

Table 2: t2

```
╔════════════╦═════╗
║ CustomerID ║ Year║
╠════════════╬═════╣
║ ACC20011   ║ 2001║
║ ACC30122   ║ 2001║
║ ACC12356   ║ 2002║
║ EVG12345   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23445   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23548   ║ 2003║
╚════════════╩═════╝
```

Table 3: t3

```
╔════════════╦═════╗
║ CustomerID ║ Year║
╠════════════╬═════╣
║ ACC20011   ║ 2001║
║ ACC30122   ║ 2002║
║ ACC00001   ║ 2003║
║ EVG00002   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23048   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23548   ║ 2001║
╚════════════╩═════╝
```

Result table : t4

```
╔════════════╦═════╗
║ CustomerID ║ Year║
╠════════════╬═════╣
║ ACC00001   ║ 2003║
║ EVG00002   ║ 2003║
║ DAA23048   ║ 2003║
╚════════════╩═════╝
```

The table t1, t2 are same. When the input given is "2003", it should check t1, t2 whether "2003" is there and copy the CustomerID of "2003" in t3 to t4.

I'm confused how to give the if condition. The year should be in all three tables. If "2003" in t1, t2, t3 then update t4.

Comment: Surely, if you're stuck on one little problem, you must have an incomplete procedure written by now.  Can you please post that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9eba8/1)

**Query**:

```
insert into t4
select * from t3
where year_nr = 2003
and exists (
    select 1 from t1
    where year_nr = 2003
    )
and exists (
    select 1 from t2
    where year_nr = 2003
    )
```

**Query**:

```
select * from t4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9eba8/1/1)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | YEAR_NR |
|-------------|---------|
|    ACC00001 |    2003 |
|    EVG00002 |    2003 |
|    DAA23048 |    2003 |
```

Comment: Is there any solution like instead of using where exists which checks during the run time. How to write if statement if the conditions are satisfied insert else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing an insert/select into t4 (assuming you don't want to merge with existing data) of the rows in t3 where the supplied year exists in the other two tables? That is:

```
insert into t4 (CustomerId, Year)
select CustomerId, Year
from t3 
where Year = :year
and exists (select 1 from t2 where Year = :year)
and exists (select 1 from t1 where Year = :year)
```